# SUBSTR twice in MySQL statement;

Tags: mysql, character, substr, trailing

So my responses are of the pattern.. "Congratulations! You have won a Panasonic Sound System in the *******. Our call centre will contact you on *********." What I need is to select only the prize (in this case Panasonic Sound System" ) as the output. The characters for the different prizes differ. Others have many characters and only 10 characters. I need to run a select statement that removes both the leading "Congratulations! You have won a " and the trailing "in the ******. Our call centre will contact you on **********." and therefore returns the prize; Lets call my table entries, my field which has this text we call it response;                                                                                                                                           I've run                                                                                                                                                          `SELECT SUBSTR(response,32) from entries; and I remove the leading characters before the prize.`

when i run this i get "Panasonic Sound System in the *******. Our call centre will contact you on **********.";

The character length of LEADING is 32 and TRAILING is 94. The prize is not constant.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) might be useful here:

```
select 
substring_index(
substring_index(
"Congratulations! You have won a Panasonic Sound System in the *. Our call centre will contact you on ***."," a ",-1)," in the ",1);
```

Comment: Thanks alot both of you for your help. Tried Jon's suggestion but had errors so i decided to try Tom Mac's. Worked at first try. Muchas Gracias Senor!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident that your trailing and leading character counts are always going to be constant, you make use of [substr's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) usage case: `SUBSTR(str,pos,len).`

`len` can be determined by subtracting the leading unwanted chars and trailing unwanted chars from the length of the original string.

```
set @test_string = "Congratulations! You have won a Panasonic Sound System in the ************************. Our call centre will contact you on *************************";
set @leading = 32;
set @trailing = 94;
select substr(@test_string, @leading, length(@test_string) - @leading - @trailing);
```

Eg:

```
mysql> select substr(@test_string, @trailing_chars, length(@test_string) - @leading_chars - @trailing_chars);
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| substr(@test_string, @trailing_chars, length(@test_string) - @leading_chars - @trailing_chars) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Panasonic Sound System                                                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```